# Ayuda con codigo de Java fecha date

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me podrian ayudar porfavor, esque tengo una fecha ej: Año/mes/dia 2018/05/05 Necesito que cuando yo unda un boton este me añada un mes 2018/06/05 pero el dia siga igual, tengo que poner la variable en Date porque lo pienso llevar a mi base de datos phpMyAdmin, Basicamente que cuando undan el boton pagar la variable en la cual tengo la fecha de ultimo pago se cambie y se adelante al siguiente mes

Comment: y si es por ejemplo enero 31, y agregas un mes, como queda la siguiente fecha? Te pregunto porque febrero no puede tener 31 dias.

Comment: Esa es una de mis grandes controversias,solo podrian hasta el 25 de cada mes para que el programa no genere error

Comment: Prueba con el método `Calendar.add()`

Comment: Yo le metería directamente los componentes de [tag:jcalendar] para mostrar más fácil las fechas

Answer (score 1):

Asi como ha mencionado @E. Betanzos, deberia usar Calendar:

```
String fechaInicial = "2018/05/05";

SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date fecha = parser.parse(fechaInicial);

Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
calendario.setTime(fecha);
calendario.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

String fechaConUnMes = formateador.format(calendario.getTime());
System.out.println("Ahora " + fechaConUnMes);
```

No lo he testeado, pero deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

No te recomiendo para nada la API de Calendar. JodaTime es una implementación mucho mejor, con un diseño mucho mas elegante. 
Tienes múchisimos métodos útiles para trabajar con fechas, entre ellos **plusMonths** que lo que hace, como bien se puede apreciar por su nombre, es sumar n meses a tu objeto fecha.
Te muestro dis ejemplos:

El primero es el caso que tu planteas, tengo 2018/05/05 y debo obtener 2018/06/05. En el segundo caso tengo 2016/01/29 (año bisiesto) y debo obtener 2016/02/29

```
    public class FechasTest {

        private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

        @Test
        public void debeAumentarUnMesALaFecha() {

            LocalDate fecha = formatter.parseDateTime("2018/05/05").toLocalDate();
            LocalDate fechaEsperada = formatter.parseDateTime("2018/06/05").toLocalDate();

            assertThat(fecha.plusMonths(1)).isEqualTo(fechaEsperada);
        }

        @Test
        public void obtengo29DeFebreroPorqueEsUnAnioBisiesto() {

            LocalDate fecha = formatter.parseDateTime("2016/01/29").toLocalDate();
            LocalDate fechaEsperada = formatter.parseDateTime("2016/02/29").toLocalDate();

            assertThat(fecha.plusMonths(1)).isEqualTo(fechaEsperada);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pero el problema esque no me sirve porque no es con fechas establecidas si no que es una fecha que ya tendo en mi base de datos

Comment: Tanto uses Calendar, JodaTime o la API que sea para manejar fechas, vas a tener que adaptar el dato que viene de la base de datos a Java y viceversa, cosa que hacen por nosotros las api de persistencia. Si necesitas un Date de java, JodaTime posee un método **toDate()** que transforma de JodaTime a Date.
        LocalDate fecha = formatter.parseDateTime("2018/05/05").toLocalDate();
        Date fechaTipoDate = fecha.toDate();